# Obtain data from JSon after choosing a field with a JQuery UI slider

Tags: javascript, html, json, jquery-ui, slider

I'm doing a webpage that contains a JQuery UI slider, where you can select a year. After the stop event of the slider, I want the webpage to show the data from a JSon file related to the year I have chosen.
First, I would like to know if doing this dinamically is possible (I'm using HTML + CSS + JavaScript).

And second, here is the stop event of the slider:

```
    stop: function (event, ui) {
        alert('Stopped at ' + ui.value);            

        $.getJSON('winners.json', function(winners) {
            var output=" ";

            output+=winners.driver[ui.value].name;
            document.getElementById("winner").innerHTML=output;
        });
    }
```

The alert shows properly the year selected in the slider.

winners.json has 2 fields (year, name), driver is the name of the JSon Array and winner is a placeholder in the HTML

Comment: *"I would like to know if doing this dinamically is possible"* Yes, it is. Are you having any problems with your code?

Comment: Sorry, I forgor to put the problem :)it shows the alert with no problem, but the webpage doesn´t show the name field.

Comment: [Have a look at the console and see if you get any errors](http://www.netmagazine.com/tutorials/javascript-debugging-beginners). If it doesn't show the name, then either the structure of your data is different than you think or the response could not be parsed. There is not much else we can say about it, since we neither know the real structure of `winner` nor what `ui.value` is.

Comment: I wil try with the console, thanks. ui.value is the actual selected value in the slider. winner is a label in the html where I want to show the name. I think that label should work that way, because it's coded like the example in here http://jqueryui.com/resources/demos/slider/rangemax.html

Comment: The console says "XMLHttpRequest cannot load file", so I will try first to fix this. Thanks for the console tip.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From your description of `winners.json`, it sounds like you have an object named `driver` that contains an array. Each object in the array has two fields: `year` and `name`. Then, you are trying to access the `name` field as if it was nested within the `year` field...instead of being a sibling of the `year` field. If this is the case, you either need to restructure your `winners.json` file to match your code, or easier...change your code to access the `name` correctly.

If they are siblings, you could do something like this:

```
for (var i=0,len=winners.driver.length; i < len; i++) {
    if(winners.driver[i].year === ui.value){
        output += winners.driver[i].name;
    }
}
```

Also, make sure that the `winners.json` file is uploaded to your web server, and you are specifying the correct path when you make your call. Based on what you have, it would be looking in the same directory as your HTML file that's making the call.