# Receiving undefined value from JSon

Tags: javascript, json

According to my previous [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17252443/obtain-data-from-json-after-choosing-a-field-with-a-jquery-ui-slider), I'm trying to obtain a name from a JSon file named winners.json, whose format is similar to this:

```
    {"driver":[
      {
        "Year":1984,
        "Name":"Name1",
      },
      {
        "Year":1985,
        "Name":"Name2",
      },
    [etc...]
    ]}
```

In the JavaScript file, I get a value from a slider, that will be the year I want to search in the JSon file. Using the console, the typeof of that value is "number". But when I go all over the JSon searching for the year, the console says that "Year" fields in the Json are undefined values, so I can't get the "Name" field:

```
    var len=winners.winner.length;
    console.info(len + " values in JSon");
    for (var i=0; i < len; i++) {
        console.info("Reading line " + i + " Type: " + typeof(winners.winner[i].Year) + " Year: " + winners.winner[i].Year);
        [more code...]
    }
```

The var len is correctly read. I tried doing a casting Number(winners.winner[i].Year), but I get NaN value.

Thanks.

Comment: Can you put up the exact winners.json file you used?

Comment: Sorry, I mixed 2 projects in the questio, it is not driver array, it is winner array. The JSon is correctly formed       
    {"winner":[
      {
        "Year":1984,
        "Name":"Name1",
      },
      {
        "Year":1985,
        "Name":"Name2",
      },
    [etc...]
    ]}

Comment: can you put this in fiddle?

Comment: How do I put the JSon in fiddle? Anyways, it will be maybe difficult to understand.The entire code is written in Spanish, and I modified the esential parts (JSon included) so you could understand

Comment: @TitoMc your code works in the following sample: http://jsfiddle.net/Hqh76/

Comment: it's maybe that var winners = JSON.parse(jsondata); line? I didn't add it to my code

Comment: If `len` is correct, then you have the right structure (winners is an object with a field `winner`, and winners.winner has a length parameter).  Can you `console.info(winners.winner[i])` within the loop and see if there's a line that's missing the Year field?

Comment: if I console.info(winners.winner[i]) I get [object Object] in all the lines

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming your code looks similar to the following:

```
var jsondata = '{"winner":[ { "Year":1984, "Name":"Name1" }, { "Year":1985, "Name":"Name2" }]';

console.info(jsondata.length)     

for (var i=0; i < len; i++) {
   console.info("Reading line " + i + " Type: " + typeof(jsondata.winner[i].Year) + " Year: " +
   winners.winner[i].Year);
}
```

Then it is correct that the `len` variable will return a positive integer, this will not however be the number of array elements in your JSON but instead the number of characters in the string. As mentioned by @Nirk, a call to `JSON.parse(jsondata);` is needed to turn the JSON string into a JavaScript object.

Comment: I'm getting the JSon from a different file, winners.json with $.getJSON('winners.json', function(winners){...}); all the code is inside. Do I need that parse?